# JEditable Passing Custom Parameters

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am trying to pass custom parameter(@item.CompanyId) to editable function and tried lots of things. I am looping in a model and need to pass 2 parameters. id parameter seems OK. But could not pass the CompanyID..

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="edit" data-rel="@item.CompanyId" id="@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnswerText)</div>
            }


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".edit").editable("/Profile/SaveMyAnswer",
            {
                id: "answerId",
                 submitdata : { 
                     CompanyId: function () {
                         return $(this).attr('rel');
                        }
            }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved like below.

1. I have added a name attribute which contains my CompanyId,

   ```
   <div class="items" name="@item.CompanyId" id="@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnswerText)</div>
   ```
2. Change the script as below

   $(document).ready(function () {

   ```
       $(".items").each(function () {
           var selectedCompanyId = $(this).attr("name");
           $(this).editable('/Profile/SaveMyAnswer', {
               id   : 'answerId',
               name : 'answerText',
               submitdata: function () {
                   return { CompanyId: selectedCompanyId };
               }
           });
       });
   });
   ```